# Toggle only when parent list items is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a simple `ol li` based list which toggles when i click on parent item or child item. I want it to toggle only when parent item is clicked.

```
$("#expList > li").click(function () {
    $(this).find("ol").slideToggle();
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/k2jqqbbk/3/

I tried to target it with `$("#expList ol li")` but this is not working. I tried few other options which didn't work either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the `event.target` to check whether its closest `li` contains an `ol`, and only toggle if it does:

```
$('#expList > li').click(function(evt) {

    if ($(evt.target).closest('li').has('ol').length) {     
        $(this).find("ol").slideToggle();
    }

});
```

#### [Here's a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/k2jqqbbk/29/)

Answer (score 1):

You need to target the `a` tag. Because the `ol` is the next child, the `find` call has been replaced with a call to `next`:

```
$("#expList > li > a").click(function () {
  $(this).next().slideToggle();
});
```

If you want the functionality to extend to children of children, just omit `#expList` from the selector:

```
$("li > a").click(function () {
    $(this).next().slideToggle();
});
```

**[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yassarikhan786/k2jqqbbk/20/)**

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the following code :

```
$("#expList > li").click(function () {
    $(this).find("ol").slideToggle();
});

$("#expList > li ol li").click(function () {
    return false;
});
```

Comment: This renders link use less i can't open the child links this way

Answer (score 0):

The click event bubbles up to ancestor elements. So the click is fired first against the second-level list items, then bubbles up to the first-level list items. This is why you're seeing the toggling happen.

All you need to do is stop the click event bubbling up the element chain from the second-level list items.

Add this to fix:

```
    $("#expList ol li").click(function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
    });
```

Here's the example: https://jsfiddle.net/sxn5bg3x/